# NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition not specified on a single edge

Tags: differential-equations

> NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition c[t,5]==Cout is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain. >>

I'd like to plot $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}c=\frac{d}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}c) \equiv\Delta c $ with the initial condition $c(0,r)=c_{0}$ and the boundary conditions $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}c(t,0)=0$ and $c(t,R\in\mathbb{R})=c_{out}$ where $R$ is the radius of a circle. I know the analytical solution and I know how the profile looks. I'd like to use/learn Mathematica because it often helps if you can make a quick plot of unknown shapes.

```
NDSolve[{D[c[t, r], t] == d/(r^2) D[((r^2) D[c[t, r], r]), r],
Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == 0, c[t, 5] == cout,c[0, r] == c0}, 
c, {t, 0, 10}, {r, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error occurs because the range in `r` is given as `{r, -5, 5}` but the boundary condition `Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == 0` is given at `r = 0`, which is not a boundary.  I imagine that `{r, 0, 5}` is meant, which eliminates the error.  However, the equation is singular at `r = 0`, which creates other errors.  This is a common issue in spherical coordinates.  An easy work-around is to displace the inner radial boundary slightly, say to `r = 0.01`.  Finally, all constants need to be specified.  In all, I modified the code to

```
cout = 1; c0 = 2; d = 1;
ans = NDSolveValue[{D[c[t, r], t] == d/(r^2) D[((r^2) D[c[t, r], r]), r], 
   Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0.01] == 0, c[t, 5] == cout, c[0, r] == c0},
   c, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0.1, 5}];
```

and then plotted the solution

```
Plot3D[ans[t, r], {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0.01, 5}, AxesLabel -> {t, r, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This may get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the example code and explanation! Actually my version does not support NDSolveValue and NDSolve returns `NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent` and the plot is empty. Your guess on the BC was right. My attempt by choosing {r,-5,5} was to get a symmetrically continued function plot over r<0 (mirroring at the c-t-plane).
Thanks a lot for your welcoming comment.

Comment: `NDSolve` works just as well, and you usually can ignore the warning.  See the documentation  of `NDSolve` on how to extract and plot the results it produces.

Comment: Specifically, replace `NDSolveValue[...` by `First@NDSolve[...`, and `ans[t, r]` by `(c /. ans)[t, r]` in `Plot3D`.

Comment: I already tried `ans = NDSolve[{D[c[t, r], t] == d/(r^2) D[((r^2) D[c[t, r], r]), r], 
   Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0.01] == 0.01, c[t, 5] == cout, 
   c[0, r] == c0}, c, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0.01, 5}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 1000}}]` with `Plot3D[Evaluate[c[t, r] /. ans], {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0.01, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, r, c}, PlotRange -> {1, 3}]`
In both cases I only see a 2D plane constant to 2. Where MethodOfLines option was used to overcome the inconsistent boundary warning.

Comment: What values are you using for your constants?.  If `cout=c0=2`, the answer is `2` everywhere.

Comment: No, I took your suggestions (these values already reveal all important aspects of the surface). It's maybe a bug (specific to above IC/BCs).